# How to protect HTML form from blank submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically I'm using this tutorial: [HTML FORM](https://phppot.com/jquery/php-contact-form-with-jquery-ajax/)

Everything is working as it should but one flow I've found is that everyone can see the `URL` for your `.php` which in this case is "url: "contact_mail.php""
Is there a way to protect my form from blank submission when someone type the `url` and just press enter. 
**Example:** www.mywebsite.com/contact_mail.php

Thank you!

Comment: do you mean submitting empty fields?

Comment: first apply a jquery client side validation for your form fields than also applied to server side on contact_mail.php to check any blanks fields

Comment: Making fields `required` should help a little (at least with modern browsers), not perfect, but does its job

Comment: Example which you provide https://phppot.com/jquery/php-contact-form-with-jquery-ajax/  has validation function which  check for empty  form

Comment: Yes the form has validation but when you type the url, as I mentioned, empty fields are send to the email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can use the [`required`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute on mandatory fields for client-side:

```
<input type="text" name="mandatory_field" required>
```

But you will need to verify server-side in case the user modified the form. You can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) on any variable (`$_POST` or `$_GET`):

```
if (empty($_POST['mandatory_field'])) {
    // print error message or redirect to form page
}
```

You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to verify if a field is submitted. Your validation could be:

```
if (!isset($_POST['mandatory_field']) || empty($_POST['mandatory_field'])) {
    // print error message or redirect to form page
}
```

---

**Other cases:**
If all fields are mandatory you could check with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array(false, $_POST)) {
    // print error message or redirect to form page
}
```

If doing various data validation here is what I use to do with forms:

```
$errors = [
    'empty field'           => empty($_POST['field']),
    'another error message' => $another_condition
];

if (in_array(true, $errors)) {
    $error_message = array_search(true, $errors);
    // print or redirect, and you can tell the user what is wrong
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've performed additional checks with the isset() and empty() all working perfect now.

Comment: @angelo942 glad it helped you !

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following form;

```
<form action="savething.php" method="GET" name="mythingform">
    <input name="thing1" type="text" />
    <input name="thing2" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateAndSubmit()" />
</form>
```

In this, instead of a submit type input, I have used a button. This means, something needs to happen before the page will submit, so, for example;

```
<script>
    function validateAndSubmit()
    {
        var thing1 = document.getElementsByName("thing1")[0];
        var thing2 = document.getElementsByName("thing2")[0];

        if (thing1.value.length > 0 && thing2.value.length > 0)
        {
            document.forms["mythingform"].submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The JavaScript function here will only call the submit on the form when the inputs are not empty

In terms of stopping someone from accessing this without permission;

```
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST['myvariable'] || empty($_REQUEST['myvariable']))
    die("Please make sure the form has been submitted properly with all required information");
```

Using `die` in this, will terminate execution of the script any further, you can also use `exit` and both allow you have have a "termination message" attached to them as part of the stoppage process

`$_REQUEST` isn't the safest of options, but it permits you to use GET or POST methods from forms to be able to retrieve and use data

Answer (score 0):

Form blank submission you can use java-script validation or jquery validation validation or you can also use php validation to avoid blank form submission.

### core js validation

simple example:

```
   var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
   if (x == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
   }
```

### jquery validation

validation library 
https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

example:

```
$("#myform").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
     // some other code
     // maybe disabling submit button
     // then:
     $(form).submit();
   }
  });
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

(1) there should be no danger from someone 'just entering' the URL in their browser - the back-end code is supposed to respond only to POST, not to GET (entering a URL in a browser makes it issue a GET request for the given URL).

(2) the quoted example code already includes client-side validation (including checks for empty fields), so if someone legitimately uses your entry form, they will not be able to send a blank form.

(3) all that remains is to protect the back-end code from accidental or malicious posting of empty forms (and any other use that is undesirable). The example PHP code doesn't have any checks, you should add some - like the `isset(...)` or `empty()` checks suggested in another answer here).

Answer (score -2):

Use if (empty($_POST['your_field']))

So if a post or get query reaches your php script, empty will check if the field is empty or not.

So something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['your_field'])) {
    echo 'Field xxx should not be empty';
}
```

Although isset would be better, since if they just go to the link, your POST and GET variables are empty.
So something like this is kinda foolproof:

```
if (!isset($_POST['your_field']) || empty($_POST['your_field'])) {
    echo 'Field xxx should not be empty';
}
```

Didn't think i'd need a separate piece of code for GET, but ok.

```
if (!isset($_GET['your_field']) || empty($_GET['your_field'])) {
    echo 'Field xxx should not be empty';
}
```

Comment: this will only check POST variable, and not GET edit your answer

Comment: Or use `$_REQUEST`, that's a semidecent catch all for post/get

Comment: its also better to use isset, incases where he could be submitting in same page